# Unable to load class get.spock.GebSpec due to missing dependency org/spockframework/mock/MockController

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

What is wrong with my test framework, that I cannot run my test?

my **build.gradle**

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
//task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
//   gebVersion = '0.13.1'
//    seleniumVersion = '2.52.0'
//
//  distributionUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$gradleVersion-all.zip"
//}


apply plugin: 'groovy'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.5

    dependencies {
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
        // geb
        compile 'org.codehaus.geb:geb-core:0.7.2'
        compile 'org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:0.7.2'
       compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.52.0"
        compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:2.52.0"
        compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:2.52.0"
        compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.52.0"
        // spock
        compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.1"
        testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4"
    }
```

My **GebConfig.groovy**

```
    //import geb.driver.SauceLabsDriverFactory
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
    import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver

    //baseUrl = 'http://madison.craigslist.org'

    // default driver...
    System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', "../resources/chromedriver")
    driver = {new ChromeDriver()}

    environments {

                'chrome' {
                    def chromeDriver = new File('src/test/resources/chromedriver') // add .exe for Windows...
                    System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', chromeDriver.absolutePath)
                    driver = { new ChromeDriver() }
                }

    //            'ff' {
    //                driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }
    //                driver.manage().window().maximize()
    //            }

                'safari' {
                    driver = { new SafariDriver() }
                }
    }

    waiting {
        timeout = 6
        retryInterval = 0.5
        slow { timeout = 12 }
        reallySlow { timeout = 24 }
    }

    reportsDir = "geb-reports"
```

**page class**

```
    package pages

    import geb.Page
    import geb.Browser

    class LoginPage extends Page{

        static url = "https://qmdev.quickblox.com"
    //  static at = {heading.isDisplayed()}
        static at = {title == "Q-municate"}

        static content = {
            heading {$("div#l-welcome_block l-welcome_text_description")}
            logInByEmailOrSocial {$("button", text:"login by email or social")}
            logInPageTitle {$("div.l-welcome_block l-welcome_text_login")}
        }
    }
```

**test class**

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import pages.LoginPage
import spock.lang.*
import geb.spock.GebSpec


@Stepwise
class LoginPageTest extends GebReportingSpec{

    def "log in Q-municate"(){
        given: "Open Log In page"
        to LoginPage

        when: "chose log in by email"
        LoginPage.logInByEmailOrSocial.click()

        then: "Ensure that we are on LogIn page"
        LoginPage.logInPageTitle.text() == "Log In"
    }
}
```

About my framework:
I use web-spock-groovy-gradle bundle for web UI automation and I'm a fresh-user with Gradle.
Please tell me, what is wrong with my build.gradle and GebConfig.groovy.

Comment: Why's geb a compile dependency, but Spock a test compile?

Comment: A typo in your import maybe? It is `geb.spock.GebSpec`, not `get.spock`. Or is it just a typo in your headline?

Answer (score 0):

your Geb-Spock version of 0.7.2 is quite old and could be the cause of your problem. I suggest changing those 2 dependencies up to version 1.1.1:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.geb:geb-core:0.7.2'  //change to 1.1.1
compile 'org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:0.7.2' //change to 1.1.1
```

Further more I check the Spock API version 1.1 for "org/spockframework/mock/MockController" and it does not appear to exist.

[image]

(http://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.1-SNAPSHOT/index.html)
As you can see in this picture there are only 2 classes that are part of the spock.mock package, and MockController is not one of them. try updating your geb version and let us know if that helps